# USB debugging turns off after restart on Android 7.0

Tags: usb, debug

Recently, my Moto G4 running Android 7.0 has been turning off USB debugging under developer options whenever the phone restarts. Is there a way to keep it on all the time? I have already tried revoking and reauthorizing the USB debugging authorizations.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you Sir!:
If you have further questions, don't hesitate to ask me.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7KdH4j7aAPM

Comment: This might be the answer, but as of current writing, it's considered as "link-only" because YouTube video can be taken down/offline at anytime, thus making this answer useless. Consider [edit]ing and putting the detail/steps as a text instead. Thank you.